# Issues using knife bootstrap on FreeBSD 10

Tags: freebsd, chef, knife

I'm fairly certain this is unrelated to my cookbook, since the following occurs immediately after connecting:

```
0.0.0.0 Unmatched '.
0.0.0.0 distro=FreeBSD: Command not found.
0.0.0.0 distro: Undefined variable.
0.0.0.0 if: Expression Syntax.
0.0.0.0 then: Command not found.
0.0.0.0 PATH=/usr/sfw/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin: Command not found.
0.0.0.0 export: Command not found.
0.0.0.0 fi: Command not found.
0.0.0.0 fi: Command not found.
0.0.0.0 Badly placed ()'s.
0.0.0.0 Invalid null command.
0.0.0.0 then: Command not found.
0.0.0.0 return: Command not found.
0.0.0.0 else: endif not found.
```

I was unable to determine this from reading the documentation and threads related to FreeBSD for Chef, but got the impression that compatibility was slow going for FreeBSD 9.x (and 10, by extension), so I'm mostly trying to determine if I should continue pounding away at this if it's not strictly supported.

Not sure if it's relevant, but the command I used was:

```
knife bootstrap $IP --run-list "recipe[freebsd-baseline]" -x root -P "$PASSWORD" -N $HOSTNAME
```

FreeBSD version:

```
# uname -rs
FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE
```

Anyone else come across this before? Is there an official resource for determining a supported FreeBSD version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've specified a custom bootstrap template [this is what bootstrap is trying to run](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-full.erb).

At the very least it expects both `bash` and either `wget` or `curl` to be installed, and findable via `PATH`. It's been awhile since I've used FreeBSD, but I remember that none of those things were included in a default install last time I did one.

I've recently said some mean things to the guy that wrote most of chef, and I both stand by those things and shudder to think what kind of half-baked support there is for FreeBSD.

Godspeed.

Comment: Sheesh. Yeah, my recipe installs bash, so that makes sense lol. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the bootstraped node, change the default shell for the root user to bash, i.e.:

```
# chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

This should do the job, assuming you've already installed chef-client on the node.